# Сортировка базы данных

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite

Требуется отсортировать базу данных:

```
| 1 | 2 | 3  |
|---|---| ---|
| аа| а | 111|
| bb| а | 222|
| bb| b | 123|
| cc| а | 123|
| cc| b | 123|
| cc| c | 123|
```

Я беру значение "а" из колонки 2 нахожу таких же "а" в итоге должно получится так:

```
| 1 | 2 | 3  |
|---|---| ---|
| аа| а | 111|
| bb| а | 222|
| cc| а | 123|
```

Нахожу минимальное число из колонки 3:

```
| 1 | 2 | 3  |
|---|---| ---|
| аа| а | 111|
```

После того как определилось со значением "а" переходим к "b" и так до конца.
Как можно это реализовать это в коде?
Я предполагаю что это будет в цикле.
Это всего лишь пример, так этих значений из колонки 2 в моей базе 8 шт не больше не меньше.

Comment: что за база данных? в каком формате данные ваши?

Comment: База данных sqlite5 в формате .db. Через питон записываю читаю т.д. Я плохо понимаю что вы хотите уточнить.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table table1 (
 field1 text,
 field2 text,
 field3 integer
);

insert into table1 select 'aa', 'a', 111;
insert into table1 select 'bb', 'a', 222;
insert into table1 select 'bb', 'b', 123;
insert into table1 select 'cc', 'a', 123;
insert into table1 select 'cc', 'b', 234;
insert into table1 select 'cc', 'c', 123;

select 
  (select field1 from table1 where field2 = t1.field2 order by field3 limit 1) field1,
  t1.field2 field2,
  min(t1.field3) field3
from 
  table1 t1 
group by 
  t1.field2;
```